# How to set option for validation constraint in Symfony globally?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-validator

I need to change [format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html#format) for [DateTime](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html) validation constraint but I want to do it globally for the whole application to not copy-paste it like this:

```yaml
dateFrom:
  - DateTime
      format: Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP
dateTo:
  - DateTime
      format: Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP
```

*(I use yaml config in my application)*

Is there any option to do it globally in Symfony 5 application, using DI parameters or some other way?

I didn't find anything about it in official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom constraint extending `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime` and set the format there.

```
// src/Validator/Constraints/MyDateTime.php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime as BaseDateTime;

class MyDateTime extends BaseDateTime
{
    public $format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        // use the same validator without this symfony will look for 'App\Validator\Constraints\MyDateTimeValidator' 
        //return static::class.'Validator';

        return parent::class.'Validator';
    }
}
```

Then you just use custom constraint where needed.

### YAML:

```
# config/validator/validation.yaml
App\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        createdAt:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - App\Validator\Constraints\MyDateTime: ~
```

### Annotations:

```
// src/Entity/Author.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use App\Validator\Constraints as MyAssert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @MyAssert\MyDateTime 
     * @var string A "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP" formatted value
     */
    protected $createdAt;
}
```

So your config would look like this:

```
dateFrom:
  - App\Validator\Constraints\MyDateTime: ~
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html